# Do "unrar" and "unzip" deserve their own tags?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

Do we really need [rar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rar) and [unrar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unrar), [zip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zip) and [unzip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unzip)?

Please note that `unrar`, `unzip` and `gunzip` are command line utilities.

Comment: Combine them to two tags, RAR and ZIP?

Comment: There's also `gzip` and `gunzip`…

Comment: Is there anything to gain from having [zip], [rar], etc., as opposed to just using the general tag [compression] (and [extract])?

Answer (score 14):

IMHO: Nope, we do not need either of these four.

Especially not both the compress **and** the decompress version of the tags. Even if people vote for keeping them I suggest removing at least unrar/unzip

Answer (score 8):

I think that there are cases when having the specific tags would help. I think the extra decompression tags are overkill. Just have [zip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zip), [rar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rar), and [gzip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/gzip) and then make [compression](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compression) and [extraction](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/extraction) for general questions.

Comment: I believe that extraction may be too wide a term as it may imply extracting data from something.

Answer (score 5):

I'd give a differing view here. There's specific [unrar](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unrar) and [unzip](http://linux.die.net/man/1/unzip) binaries in common use, so this is not your classic meta-tag. This would be like demanding we kill off the [7zip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/7zip) tag, IMO.

Comment: Not sure about unrar, but unzip is almost always linked to zip.

Answer (score 4):

Just my opinion maybe,  but I think the [compression](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compression) is quite sufficient. It automatically implies (de)compression. At most there should be only two tags [compression](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compression) and [decompression](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/decompression) for the if for the sake of clarity.

Answer (score 2):

I believe [compression](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compression) should be sufficient for all (de)compression related questions.

I would also synomymise [zip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zip) and [rar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/rar) to [compression](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/compression) so that people find it when attempting to tag with the aforementioned tags.

[unrar](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unrar) and [unzip](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/unzip) should just be burned on sight.

Answer (score -1):

I think that these tags should stand for the time being, but a note should be made that when the Internet is full up they will be the first things removed.

Comment: How does this answer the question? ( I didn't downvote yet.)